# How to force exclude Spring @Configuration picked up by recursive @ComponentScan

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

Our top level @ComponentScan scans a package, which in turn contains @ComponentScan that picks up a @Configuration class we want to ignore.  Using excludeFilters on the top level @ComponentScan doesn't seem to let us to exclude the @Configuration we want to avoid.

We are trying to add a dependency to our spring project, and with @ComponentScan, bring in the libraries we want.

However, there is one @Configuration class we want to exclude, as it contains a @Bean using deprecated GuavaCache from spring 4.  We are using spring 5, so get a NoClassDefFoundError if try to use the class.

Simple to create our own implementation using the newer spring 5 cache, but can't figure out how to exclude the existing @Configuration.  The base package we need to scan is not the one containing the bad class, but instead scans a package which contains other classes with @ComponentScan annotations, which causes it to get picked up.

the annotations we've tried at top level spring-boot Application class, classes in thirdparty.infrastructure.requestcontext are what then @ComponentScan to find JwtCacheConfig we want to exclude

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.ourpackage",
    "thirdparty.infrastructure.requestcontext"},
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,
        pattern = "fourthparty\\.common\\.jwtvalidation\\.domain\\.config\\..*"))
public class MyApplication
```

also tried:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.ourpackage",
    "thirdparty.infrastructure.requestcontext"},
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
        classes = fourthparty.common.jwtvalidation.domain.config.JwtCacheConfig.class))
public class MyApplication
```

class to ignore:

```
package fourthparty.common.jwtvalidation.domain.config

import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.cache.Cache
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching
import org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class JwtCacheConfig {

    @Value('${px.cache.jwtPublicKeys.maximumSize:50}')
    Integer maximumCacheSize

    @Value('${px.cache.jwtPublicKeys.expireAfterWrite:1440}')
    Integer expirationTime

    @Bean
    Cache jwtPublicKeyCache(){
        return new GuavaCache('jwtPublicKeys', CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(maximumCacheSize).expireAfterWrite(expirationTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build(), true)
    }
}
```

The class we want to put in place

```
package com.ourpackage.config

import java.time.Duration

import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.cache.Cache
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching
import org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCache
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class MyJwtCacheConfig
{
    @Value('${px.cache.jwtPublicKeys.maximumSize:50}')
    Integer maximumCacheSize

    // cache it for 24 hours (60 min * 24 hours)
    @Value('${px.cache.jwtPublicKeys.expireAfterWrite:1440}')
    Integer expirationTime

    @Bean
    Cache myJwtPublicKeyCache(){
        def cacheMap = Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofMinutes(expirationTime))
            .maximumSize(maximumCacheSize)
            .build()
        return new CaffeineCache('jwtPublicKeys', cacheMap, true)
    }
}
```

Each time trying to start application, that class we want to exclude still gets picked up, and we get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCache

...
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/GenericCacheConfiguration.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 0; 

  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'jwtPublicKeyCache' defined in class path resource
[fourthparty/common/jwtvalidation/domain/config/JwtCacheConfig.class]:
Bean instantiation via factory method failed;

  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.Cache]:
Factory method 'jwtPublicKeyCache' threw exception;

  nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCache
```

Comment: Maybe you could tell us a bit more about your use case and why you have a configuration that you obviously don't need

Comment: In the `pattern`  field inside `@ComponentScan`, try giving value as "fourthparty.common.jwtvalidation.domain.config.JwtCacheConfig"

Comment: We have corporate libraries from other departments we need to use that are closed source.  we've been told to put security in our application, we need to use the corporate libraries, but the downstream inclusion of GuavaCache is causing us problems.  We've got the ok to replace that class with the Caffeine cache, but we can't push that change to the library, just an addition to our application.

We just want spring to ignore that class entirely, figure there must be something with exclusions we can do?